# Determining the basis and dimension of some vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am familiar with finding the basis and dimension of simpler vector spaces but ones like the following are giving me some trouble; so I would appreciate some general hints/explanation on generating a basis for them:

- For the field of reals $R$, let the vector space be a set of functions from $R\to R$ which are solutions to some differential equation (e.g. $2 \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} + 5f =0$)
- For $R$ again, and a more standard vector space being the set of all vectors $(a, b, c)$ in $R^3$ such that $a + b - c = 0$ (I assume this means the standard basis is out of the question as it doesn't adhere to some condition placed on a,b,c)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* These are both subsets of some larger vectors space: the space of functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ in the first case, and the $\mathbb R^3$. You don’t need to verify *all* of the vector space axioms to show that these subsets are subspaces because they will “inherit” many of the required properties from the parent space, but there are a few key ones that you do have to check. A key property to verify is closure under addition and scalar multiplication. There are a couple of others that need to be checked as well.

So, for instance, for the second subset, if you have two vectors $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ that both satisfy the equation, does their sum also satisfy it? Does a scalar multiple of $\mathbf v$ satisfy the equation? Similarly, if you have two functions that both satisfy the given differential equation, does their sum satisfy it?